# Test Automation Tool - drop-or-click or hard coding

Tags: automated-testing

What consideration and why do you need to take account to when you gonna implement a test automation tool that is drop-or-click or hard coding (SoapUI, watin, seleniumhq etc)? Any pros and cons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it comes down to your familiarity with programming in general. Entry level people will use Selenium IDE, Telerik Test Studio, or something like that (record and click). The minute you need something that isn't right out of the box, you are going to need to learn/use programming to make custom steps. This would be exporting Selenium IDE to Java and running you custom code using JUnit, for example. In Telerik, it would be a 'coded step' with VB or C#.

If you choose the programmatic route you should consider its impact on your department. If you go with a programmatic approach then your new hires will either have to be skilled in your chosen toolkit or you will have to train them up.

Another thing is cost analysis. How long will it take you to train a new hire or manual tester to use the tool? How long does it take to do the same task in each tool you compare? How much daily effort is there is keeping things running? Time is money and I have found that while free tools *can* get the job done it just takes longer. Paid tools often come with the framework to integrate with source control, email you results, run at scheduled times on specific computers and browsers, reports for bugs over time, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help! What type of tool for c# in relation to hard coding do you recommend me to use?

Comment: You can use almost any language with Selenium WebDriver. Here is an example from my blog, http://timothycope.com/?p=241. I now use Telerik and can do cool stuff like using the Fiddler core proxy to watch network traffic, rest api testing, and load testing (all done in coded steps).